Microsoft Graph API - access denied when trying to fetch permissions for a calendar with delegated permissions
I'm trying to fetch the permissions for a Microsoft 365 group calendar using delegated permissions in Microsoft Graph API. I've granted all the required API permissions, but I'm still get an access denied error.
Here's the endpoint I'm using:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/calendar/calendarPermissions

Despite having all the necessary permissions granted, I get the following error:
Error message
Additional Information:

I've ensured that the signed-in user has sufficient privileges.
All required permissions are granted, and consent has been given for the necessary scopes.

Steps taken:

Checked and confirmed that all necessary permissions are granted in Azure AD.
Verified that the signed-in user has the appropriate role and permissions.
Used the correct group ID in the API call.

Question: why am I getting this "ErrorAccessDenied" error despite having all required permissions? Is there something I'm missing in terms of permissions or configuration that needs to be addressed to successfully fetch the calendar permissions?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

What permission have you granted? Which account are you using to get the access token?

Most likely its the user your trying to use doesn't have permissions to the actual folder, eg can you access that group folder as that user in Outlook or OWA ?. To see the permissions of the folder you would need to have underlying Exchange permissions on the DCAL of the folder not just API permissions.

I used a global admin account and granted the Group.ReadWrite.All and Calendar.ReadWrite.All permissions.

Actually, I am trying to access the permissions of a certain public group's calendar using the account of the group's owner. Despite being the owner and a global admin, I still encounter this error
